# How can I enable offline web application for Chrome, Opera

Tags: html, html5-appcache

http://t2.hellocw.com/index.html is an  offline web application, it works well on FireFox
but I found the offline web application function don't work on Chrome, Opera, do I need to configure something extra for Chrome, Opera?

HTML 5 Website Source code download: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/209352/HtmlOffline.zip

Comment: do you mean Chrome/Opera didn't show a top modal asking the user for permission to store data for offline use?

Answer (score 0):

I have checked your application and I think your Application is working well in offline mode also.There is no special process for Chrome and Opera. Chrome and Opera doesn’t notify the user that the application is offline but mozrilla do it.

Comment: The offline mode of http://t2.hellocw.com/default.aspx works well in FireFox, but  offline mode of http://t2.hellocw.com/default.aspx  don't work in Chrome

Comment: I have tested it in Chrome and Mozrilla and it is working fine :)